# ubuntu 13.10 does not load up correctly

Tags: compiz

After tring to install the wizard feature of compiz, the ubuntu doesnt load up correctly. The only thing I can see is my background (the terminal doesnt work too).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant, ALT + SHIFT + F4 will open a console. Then try those compiz/unity settings reset tweaks spread on other questions on this site.